# Error when trying to Parse & Convert text from a .csv file

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, for-loop, openfiledialog

I'm currently stuck on trying to get the output of the last column in the .csv file to work. I need it to be converted to a currency. I'm not sure if I use (i == 6) for the whole column (if this even is a thing that works) or if I have to do (i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27) etc. for each value that needs to be converted to currency.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

When the Load Inventory button is clicked, inventory records will be read
from a text file using the Open File Dialog control, and the lines read from the file is tokenized into field values, parsed (as needed) and then loaded onto the listbox and the list of class instances. The ListBox (and the class instances list) should contain, in addition to all the field values in the input file, also contain columns for QtyHand and Sales. The String.Format() or PadRight() method can be used to format the listbox contents such that all values in a column are aligned assuming you are using a monospaced font.

The first two lines of the .csv file are:

```
Id,Item Name,StartingQty,QtyMinRestck,QtySold,QtyRStcked,UnitPrice
85-0521031,Shampoo,35,9,0,0,2.89
```

Any help on sorting this out is greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class inventoryForm : Form
{
    OpenFileDialog ipFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    public inventoryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loadInvDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inventoryListBox.Items.Clear(); //clear listbox items
        if (ipFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //show dialog box
        {
            string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(ipFile.FileName); //tokenize
            foreach (string line in file) //for each line in the file ...
            {
                string[] inventory = line.Split(','); //tokens contain numbers from the .csv file
                for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Length; i++) //loop goes through each item in the inventory
                {
                    if (i == 6) //items in the csv file that require conversion
                    {
                        double price = double.Parse(inventory[i]); //convert the value to currency, then pad
                        inventory[i] = String.Format("{0:C2}", price).PadRight(20, ' ');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inventory[i] = inventory[i].PadRight(20, ' '); //just pad the string
                    }
                }
                string item = string.Join("", inventory);
                inventoryListBox.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Your question is lacking both 1) a question and 2) a clear problem statement with the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Keep in mind, this isn't a 2-way conversation, it is a **question**.

Comment: My first reflex is to suggest you do this in Python.  You could do this in less than half the number of lines of code.  CSV files are a natural fit for that language, and it is easy to learn.

Comment: @SDsolar - This looks like a WinForms app, so why Python? You could actually do this in a single line using C# and linq...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making this object oriented, and this looks like Inventory. So the first step is to make an inventory class. In the Inventory class there will be method take a string as the filename to load the inventory (this may need to be modified based on your actual data types and error handling requirements).

```
    public class Inventory
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int StartingQty { get; set; }
        public int QtyMinRestck { get; set; }
        public int QtySold { get; set; }
        public int QtyRStcked { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

        public Inventory()
        {

        }

        //this overrides the default .ToString() method to provide
        //columnar output and formats the UnitPrice to currrency
        //this requires the following: using System.Globalization;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}"
                , Id.PadRight(15, ' ')
                , ItemName.PadRight(30, ' ')
                , StartingQty.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' ')
                , QtyMinRestck.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' ')
                , QtySold.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' ')
                , QtyRStcked.ToString().PadLeft(10, ' ')
                , UnitPrice.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).PadLeft(10, ' '));
        }

        //this loads a collection of inventory objects from a file
        //it would ignore any lines with errors
        public IEnumerable<Inventory> Load(string InventoryFileName)
        {
            var inventories = new List<Inventory>();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(InventoryFileName))
            {
                sr.ReadLine(); //skip the first line
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var fields = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                        inventories.Add(new Inventory
                        {
                            Id = fields[0]
                            ,
                            ItemName = fields[1]
                            ,
                            StartingQty = Int32.Parse(fields[2])
                            ,
                            QtyMinRestck = Int32.Parse(fields[3])
                            ,
                            QtySold = Int32.Parse(fields[4])
                            ,
                            QtyRStcked = Int32.Parse(fields[5])
                            ,
                            UnitPrice = Decimal.Parse(fields[6])
                        });
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //handle error here
                    }


                }
            }

            return inventories;
        }
    }
```

Now that we have the class you can easily call it and get your inventory back from the file:

inventoryListBox.Items.Clear(); //clear listbox items

```
    if (ipFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) //show dialog box
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        var inventories = inventory.Load(ipFile.FileName);
        //sets the datasource of the list box to the collection of inventory
        //by default it calls the ToString() method which which overrode
        //to provide columar output
        inventoryListBox.DataSource = inventories;
    }
```

This is a very basic implementation, but it should make things easier to maintain in the future. You could also use "inventories" as a datasource for your listbox.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I've added this code and I'm not really sure what I should be changing/modifying in the form.cs code. Sorry for being such a noob. Should I be removing everything and just call the inventory with this? ---------->


    Inventory inventory = new Inventory();

    var inventories = inventory.Load(@"c:\temp\inventory.txt");

------------------- My current output is [this](https://i.imgur.com/LCKOWPP.png)

Old output before was [this](https://i.imgur.com/B6UMFB9.png)

Comment: You would replace your for loop with the two lines of code to load inventories (replace c:\temp\inventory.txt with ipFile.Filename). For your list box it depends what you want to show. You could override ToString in the class or switch to a GridView or other control meant to show columnar data. If this isn't enough info you'll have to show your current work and ask another question.

Comment: Okay, so I got the output to load into the listbox now but it's [unformatted](http://prntscr.com/j2cpyq).  I'm not sure why.. [Here's the form.cs](https://hastebin.com/hagumocalo.cs) and the [Inventory class](https://hastebin.com/eyazixokip.cs). When I put if (i == 6) I get an error when trying to load the csv file into the listbox. I put (i == 13 || i == 20 || i == 27) to try and see if those values in the csv file would convert to $.

Comment: There's [this error](http://prntscr.com/j2d7la) in the ToString method. I don't know how to fix that. So I made a temp fix by removing the "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture" just to see how the output is. What would be the best way to keep the first line in the .csv file as headers? [Right now only the values in each column are showing without headers.](http://prntscr.com/j2d8sc)

Comment: Also if you're willing. Could you add some comments? I'm just trying to wrap my head around everything and really understand what coding you've done.

Comment: Added some comments, add a using System.Globalization to fix the CultureInfo problem. You can't add the header if you set the data source. Either put the header above this list box, use a listview or code similar to: inventoryListBox.Items.Add("header");
                foreach(var i in inventories)
                {
                    inventoryListBox.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                } THIS IS MY LAST REPLY - IF YOU HAVE MORE PROBLEMS POST ANOTHER QUESTION.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the fast solution without other details but in nutshell you need way to store newly formatted item, I hope this is clear enough for you to go on. Updated to a bit better formatted code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
        string[] list = new string[] { "85 - 0521031, Shampoo, 35, 9, 0, 0, 2.89", "86 - 0521031, Guitar, 35, 9, 0, 0, 9.89" };
        for(var i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
        {
            var listItem = list[i].Split(',');
            var outputListItem = "";

            for (var j=0; j<listItem.Length; j++)
            {
                if(j == 6)
                {
                    double price = double.Parse(listItem[j]);
                    listItem[j] = String.Format("{0:C2}", price).PadRight(20, ' '); ;
                }
                outputListItem = string.Join(" ", listItem);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(outputListItem);
            outputList.Add(outputListItem);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```